# How to implement opencyc into my project?

Tags: java, ontology, agents-jade

I download opencyc from their site. I want to use it on my project. But I do not know how to implement it on to my project. I went through documents available in the opencyc site. can anybody let me know how to use opencyc? I am using jade library...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from [the sourceforge project page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencyc/files/).
There are a couple of jars to import in `opencyc-2.0-win32.zip\opencyc-2.0\api\java\lib` before `using the OpenCyc.jar` in `opencyc-2.0-win32.zip\opencyc-2.0\api\java\build`.

Read the [faq](http://www.opencyc.org/faq/opencyc_faq#137851984) and search for download.

Comment: thank you... I already downloaded it. should I add opencyc-2.0-win32.zip\opencyc-2.0\api\java\lib into my netbeans project?

Comment: Add open cyc first. Then every time you compile your project, it will complain a class can't be found, then look at the jars in lib and add the jar containing the class. (jars open like zips). But it can be long so you are maybe better to add all the jars in libs directly + add the opencyc jar.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded opencyc-2.0-win64, extracted it, and then in `opencyc-2.0/api/java` folder, there's an Ant build.xml file. Import that project to Eclipse, as an Ant project.

Then run `org.opencyc.api.ApiDemo`... Its running perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a docker image here: https://hub.docker.com/r/bovlb/opencyc

There is the beginnings of documentation at places such as these:

http://www.pdkb.net/wiki/index.php/CycL

http://www.pdkb.net/wiki/index.php/OpenCyc

http://www.pdkb.net/wiki/index.php/SubL